# why str statement cannot be used in if....else

Tags: python

In the program, I need input integer and string.
so, I think `str` can input integer number and the English alphabet but if I use `str` and type `1` ,`2`  it also displays `Unknown [{x}]!`

```
def main():
    x=str(input("This is input "))
    if x==1:  
        print("this x1") 
        
    elif x==2:
        print("this is x2")  

    else:
        print(f"Unknown [{x}]!\n") #display user wrong input

main()
```

Comment: You might want to use `x == '1'`. Notice the quotation marks around the number

Comment: In your own words, when you write `str(input("This is input "))`, what do you think the `str` part does? In your own words, what is a string? In your own words, do you expect to be able to compare a string to an integer and have them turn out to be equal? Why or why not?

Comment: `x` is a string, so `x == 1` and `x == 2` will always be `False`.  You probably want to convert `x` to an `int`.  But if you leave it as a string, then you should compare it to strings rather than numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def main():

   x = str(input("This is input "))
   if x== '1':  
       print("this x1") 
    
   elif x== '2':
       print("this is x2")  
    

   else:
       print("Unknown [{x}]!\n\n") #display user wrong input
       main()
main()
```

since its, an str needs to have single or double quotations while comparing.

Answer (score 0):

These if checks are checking for the input of x to be an integer

```
if x==1:  
    print("this x1") 
    
elif x==2:
    print("this is x2")
```

So this will always be false because if you input 1 or 2 you get back:

- Does '1' (input)  == 1 (False String Not Equal to Int)
- Does '2'
  (input) == 2 (False ^ same as above)

If in any doubt with the types when testing, try print the type when debugging :)

```
print(type(x))
```

Put quotes around 1 and 2 in the if statements and this should work for inputs 1 and 2 :)

```
    if x == '1':
    print("this x1")
    elif x == '2':
    print("this is x2")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code that I wrote all of them:

1. As you want to convert `input` to `string`, so there's no need to use `str` function because `input` function returns `string` value by default. You can check it out by using `print(type(x))` statement.
2. `1` and `2` are `integer`, not `string`, so only `else` part executes. You should change them to `'1'` and `'2'`.

So your correct code should look like this:

```
def main():
    x=input("This is input ")
    if x == '1':  
        print("this x1") 
    elif x == '2':
        print("this is x2")  
    else:
        print(f"Unknown [{x}]!\n") #display user wrong input
    main()


main()
```